# How can I make this type of custom EditText UI?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

I am trying to put borders on edit text and put a label on it. I have tried this one. [image]

```
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<corners android:radius="15dp"/>
```

But I want the following one. Initially it will look like this. [image]

After clicking it will be like this.
[image]

Would you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ZahoorSaleem said, you can use the MaterialComponents for that.
You will need to add the [design support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#design) to your build file.

The layout would (simplified) look like this:

```
<TextInputLayout       
  android:hint="Label"
  style="style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <TextInputEditText />
</TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the material design Outline Box style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"

this link may help you http://qaru.site/questions/1688917/custom-textinputlayout-android

Answer (score -1):

```
put the below code in drawable and use this attribute in edittext
 android:background="@drawable/nameofdrawablefile"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#CC0505"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#CC0505" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```